# calculate xSteps and ySteps to get N amount of points in circle

Tags: c++, math, openframeworks

I try to fill a grid with points and only keep the points inside a imaginary circle.

[image: example]

First i did this with:
`createColorDetectionPoints(int xSteps, int ySteps)`

But for me it's a lot easier to set it with a target in mind:

`void ofxDTangibleFinder::createColorDetectionPoints(int nTargetPoints)`

The target doesn't have to be too precise. But at the moment when i want 1000 points for example i get 2289 points.

I think my logic is wrong but i can't figure it out.
The idea is to get the right amount of xSteps and ySteps.

Can someone help?

```
void ofxDTangibleFinder::createColorDetectionPoints(int nTargetPoints) {

    colorDetectionVecs.clear();

    // xSteps and ySteps needs to be calculated
    // the ratio between a rect and ellipse is
    // 0.7853982

    int xSteps = sqrt(nTargetPoints);
    xSteps *= 1.7853982; // make it bigger in proportion to the ratio
    int ySteps = xSteps;

    float centerX = (float)xSteps/2;
    float centerY = (float)ySteps/2;

    float fX, fY, d;

    float maxDistSquared = 0.5*0.5;

    for (int y = 0; y < ySteps; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < xSteps; x++) {
            fX = x;
            fY = y;
            // normalize
            fX /= xSteps-1;
            fY /= ySteps-1;

            d = ofDistSquared(fX, fY, 0.5, 0.5);

            if(d <= maxDistSquared) {
                colorDetectionVecs.push_back(ofVec2f(fX, fY));
            }
        }
    }

//    for(int i = 0; i < colorDetectionVecs.size(); i++) {
//        printf("ellipse(%f, %f, 1, 1);\n", colorDetectionVecs[i].x*100, colorDetectionVecs[i].y*100);
//    }


    printf("colorDetectionVecs: %lu\n", colorDetectionVecs.size());


}
```

Comment: A method from the openframeworks library. It just get's the distance sqaured.

Comment: What do you want to calculate? What was your intention?

Comment: @renonsz I kind of forgot since it's 2 years old but thanks for asking :)